# Add The Values of While Loop Calculation To Give Total

Tags: php, mysql

I have this statement:

```
result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, QTY, 
DESCRIPTION, UNIT_PRICE, LINE_TOTAL, CONNECT FROM b_po_line 
WHERE CONNECT = $ID");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
$qty = $row['QTY'];
$description = $row['DESCRIPTION'];
$unitPrice = $row['UNIT_PRICE'];
$lineTotal = $row['QTY']*$row['UNIT_PRICE'];

<tr><td>$qty</td><td>$description</td><td>$unitPrice</td><td>number_format($linetotal,2)</td></tr>

}
```

That works absolutely fine.  What I need to do is add up the values of the $linetotal so that it gives me a total answer, whether there is one result being returned or ten.  I'm not sure how to calculate this.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's asking for code without minimal research or show of "what have you tried?" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate like this, intialize one variable as `0`

**Ex:** `$total_lineitems = 0;`

Then update this one to your sum of  `$lineTotal` inside `while` loop like,

```
$total_lineitems  += $lineTotal;
```

Also you can't directly write your html inside `php` code. Better to concatenate with string and print it.

```
echo '<tr><td>' .$qty . '</td><td>' . $description . '</td><td>' . $unitPrice . '</td><td>' .number_format($lineTotal,2) . '</td></tr>';
```

instead of

```
<tr><td>$qty</td><td>$description</td><td>$unitPrice</td><td>number_format($linetotal,2)</td></tr>
```

Try this

```
$total_lineitems = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
   $qty = $row['QTY'];
   $description = $row['DESCRIPTION'];
   $unitPrice = $row['UNIT_PRICE'];
   $lineTotal = $row['QTY']*$row['UNIT_PRICE'];

   $total_lineitems  += $lineTotal;

    echo '<tr><td>' .$qty . 
         '</td><td>' . $description . 
         '</td><td>' . $unitPrice . 
         '</td><td>' .number_format($lineTotal,2) . 
         '</td></tr>';
}

echo $total_lineitems ;
```

Comment: @TalGleichger : Nope. I'm not copied your answer. It's my own suggest.

Comment: Used this :-) Wasn't working to begin with but that's only because += $linetotal didn't have a capital T.  Thank you so much! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
$total=0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
$qty = $row['QTY'];
$description = $row['DESCRIPTION'];
$unitPrice = $row['UNIT_PRICE'];
$lineTotal = $row['QTY']*$row['UNIT_PRICE'];
$total += $lineTotal;
echo '<tr><td>' .$qty . '</td><td>' . $description . '</td><td>' . $unitPrice . '</td><td>' .number_format($lineTotal,2) . '</td></tr>';

}
```

Comment: down voted please comment why down vote?

Comment: i am sure html does not directly work inside php unless you use echo and make it string. Copy paste wont do any good to you.

Comment: I focused on what problem user is face not what he writing. He written that working fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$grandtotal = 0;

for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
$grandtotal += $i;
}

echo $grandtotal;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize a variable before the while loop, and increment it for the value of linetotal in each cicle.

Answer (score -3):

Do something like this

```
result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ID, QTY, 
DESCRIPTION, UNIT_PRICE, LINE_TOTAL, CONNECT FROM b_po_line 
WHERE CONNECT = $ID");
$total = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2))
{
   // old code as it is

   $total+=$linetotal;


}
 echo $total;
```

Comment: It wont work. because on each loop the $total will be converted to zero again.

Comment: Oh my bad. Initialize $total outside the loop.. That would do it